# Cross reference a Python function generated by Sphinx's automodule directive from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, autodoc

Using [Sphinx's automodule](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) directive, I am creating an API documentation for all functions in my module from their respective docstrings. The respective .rst file comprises just the following lines:

```
API Reference
=============
.. automodule:: pkg_name.module_name
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

I am also integrating a Jupyter notebook into the documentation using [nbSphinx](https://pypi.org/project/nbsphinx/).

How can I cross-reference a function, which has been created by the automodule directive, from a markdown cell within the Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's admittedly a bit clunky, but that's how I would do it: https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.2/markdown-cells.html#Links-to-Domain-Objects

In other words:

If your `.rst` file is called `api_reference.rst`, you can link to the auto-generated function documentation like this:

```markdown
[my_function()](api_reference.rst#pkg_name.module_name.my_function)
```

If you don't know what exactly to put after the `#`, you can just look at the auto-generated permalink of the function documentation.
The important thing is that you use `.rst` (i.e. the extension of the source file) and not `.html` (i.e. the extension of the generated output file).

Comment: I get a file not found error.  I thought it was because the notebook is in the /notebooks directory and the .rst is in the parent, but even when I move and re-save the notebook I get the error.