# Can I refer from jupyter notebook to a section in sphinx?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have autogenerated API docs at the top of my docs directory and a notebook in the `notebooks` subdirectory like this:

```
/src
  /mypkg
    -- modname.py
/docs
  -- index.rst  # includes mynotebook.ipyx
  -- mypkg.mymod.rst  # autogenerated
  /notebooks
    -- mynotebook.ipyx
```

In sphinx a reference to modname might look like this:

```
See also the :py:mod:`mypkg.modname` documentation.
```

My question is: how can I make a reference inside the notebook that links back to API docs for the module?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763576/cross-reference-a-python-function-generated-by-sphinxs-automodule-directive-fro) question which seemingly addressed the question with this syntax:

```
[link text](mypkg.mymod.rst#mymod.modname)
```

In my case, this just returns a "file is not found". I've tried adding `..`

How do I this?

Comment: I havte the same question. Here is the relevant documentation page, but I could not find the clear answer: https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.9/a-normal-rst-file.html

Comment: Thanks. I agree this seems like the right section, and the references from sphinx to the notebook seem to work well and are understandable. The reverse -- reference in jupyter to the module documentation in sphinx -- isn't covered in an obvious way.

Comment: When you build the docs, what is the anchored link to your `modname`? You need to include the package, module, and class or function, not just the class or function.

Comment: Great point. I edited and changed the outer use of "mod" to "pkg" to reflect this. However, it was a nomenclature mistake. It is still anchored on mypkg.